# Scatter plot of two data frames using ggplot and add a Loess line in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, loess

I have two data frames which dimension are 24,523 × 3,468, and I want to get the scatter plot of them (data frame 1 in axis x and data frame 2 in axis 2)> then, I want to add a Loess line.

I can simply use a function plot() to get the scatter plot, but I do not know how to add a Loess line to the plot. Furthermore, I found that if the data for each axis is one vector only, instead of data frames, it can be done directly using a function called stat_smooth() in ggplot2 package.

My question is 1) how to get a scatter plot of two data frames using a function ggplot()? 2) How to add a Loess line to a scatter plot generated using two data frames?

This is [image: scatter_plot] what I get using

```
plot(as.matrix(spatial_data_glio_df_intersection_genes), as.matrix(estimated_all_gene_read_counts_spatial), xlab = "true_gene_read_counts", ylab = "estimated_gene_read_counts")
```

The data can be accessed using the link [data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wq00qx6mzoit7m6/AAD2nDa0C_2Xm2Phcf-2fA-ia?dl=0).

Comment: @csgroen It does not, unfortunately. Your suggestion deals with plotting the data of two single vectors, right? While my data are two data frames.

Comment: Please post some minimal data:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @harre I provided the link to access the data, cant you access it?

Comment: Each file is 40MB. A more minimal example would be appreciated

Comment: @harre Ow, that is what you meant. I will try to provide one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just linearize the two data frames with `as.vector()`. I've made a minimum reproducible example using random data. The first plot corresponds more or less to what you have currently, the second one hopefully corresponds to the desired output:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100)
df2 <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100)

plot(df1, df2, xlab = "true_gene_read_counts", ylab = "estimated_gene_read_counts")

joint_df <- data.frame(df1 = as.vector(df1), df2 = as.vector(df2))

ggplot(joint_df, aes(df1, df2)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
    labs(x = "true_gene_read_counts", y = "estimated_gene_read_counts") +
    theme_linedraw()
```

[image]

Comment: I see so the idea is to change the dataframe into vector. I got it. Yes this is what I expected. I will try using my data to see how it turns out. Thank you very much.